# Active Check delete whole ul

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in Jquery that whenever I click on checkbox and click on delete option inside div then it delete whole ul rather than its parent ul.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="delete">Delete</div>
<ul class="link" id="link">
  <li>
    <div class="style">
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled">
      <div id="style"></div>
    </div></li>
    <li class="edit">http://carouselinfo.com/canal/</li>
    <li><span class="main edit">123</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    var check = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    if(check.is(':checked')){
        //console.log("Works");
        $(this).closest("ul").empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code is meaningless (regarding your question) without your HTML markup. Please add it.

Comment: Post your HTML structure for a better Analise! On a side note, is you remove the "parent", all of its children are removed...

Comment: @FelixKling I edit my code have a  look

Comment: Your HTML has no elements with the class "delete". Plus the HTML has an error with the last `</li>` tag (there's no opening `<li>` for it to close. Aside from that, the code behaves as I would expect, emptying the list and leaving the `<ul>` and `</ul> tags only.

Comment: Emptying the *closest* `ul` will empty that `ul` which is also the *only* `ul` we can see in your code.

Comment: uau... is this your HTML? really? an `<li>` inside other `<li>`? and without an element with `class="delete"` witch is the one you call in your action ... so we know where it is.

Comment: Your HTML is still not valid.

Comment: now check @j08691 I just wrote randomly in this site..

Comment: yes http://jsfiddle.net/bXM76/ have a  look @Dejan.S

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do? it honestly is not that clear. Like explain it better. your question does not make sense with that html

Comment: I want to remove the ul element of that checkbox which is checked I mean active @Dejan.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is with your html and jquery

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/YNxgy/5/

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
var check = $("input[type='checkbox']");
check.each(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest("ul").remove();
}
});
```

}); ​

The problem was that check became a list of all the checkboxes, so you need to loop through it and check each one of them.

Comment: Yeah first I have done this thing only it also delete whole ul.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('ul').empty();
});​​​​​
```

Comment: Same response....no effect in code in (this) command it was not removing even any element also

Comment: Is the HTML you're using it on valid?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your Fiddle, it seems that what you want is to remove the parent ul of the clicked checkbox:

See the [working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/bXM76/2/)

**JQUERY**

```
// clicking the checkbox, remove parent UL
$('.link div').on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  $(this).closest('ul').remove();
});
```